# The fieldtype class “insert fieldtype class here” could not be found

Tags: database, fieldtypes, plugin-sproutseo

I'm specifically having this issue with Sprout SEO, but I would imagine the problem would persist across any plugin, given whatever solution is used.

Anywho, so I've got three environments - dev, stage, and production (live site). I've reinstalled the plugin multiple times, and checked permissions several times as well. All environments are running Ubuntu, so I know that a case-sensitivity issue ([as seen here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/5225/plugin-fieldtype-giving-error-on-live-server-fine-locally)) isn't the case.

Is there anything database related that could be causing the problem?

Or if not that, our `.gitignore` file just looks like this:

```
craft/storage/backups/
craft/storage
*.swp
public/uploads
```

Wasn't sure if anything in storage needed to be not ignored for any plugins.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: My first guess was going to be case-sensitivity. Even if they're all running Ubuntu, you can configure the file systems to be different per install. Other than that, have you verified all of the files actually exist in the correct places on the file system?